# Ошибка при выполнении метода Realm.writeCopyTo(File file)

Tags: java, android, realm

При выполнении метода `Realm.writeCopyTo(File file)` возникает представленная ниже ошибка, причем в версиях Android API отличной от 19, все работает нормально.

```
Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmIOException: Failed to access: r
      at io.realm.internal.Group.nativeWriteToFile(Native Method)
      at io.realm.internal.Group.writeToFile(Group.java:226)
      at io.realm.internal.SharedGroupManager.copyToFile(SharedGroupManager.java:141)
      at io.realm.BaseRealm.writeEncryptedCopyTo(BaseRealm.java:254)
      at io.realm.Realm.writeEncryptedCopyTo(Realm.java:122)
      at io.realm.BaseRealm.writeCopyTo(BaseRealm.java:232)
      at io.realm.Realm.writeCopyTo(Realm.java:122)
      at com.vksafer.dv.vksafer.RealmExporter$1.doInBackground(RealmExporter.java:64)
      at com.vksafer.dv.vksafer.RealmExporter$1.doInBackground(RealmExporter.java:45)
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Проверьте разрешения на запись/чтение в манифесте и почистите данные приложения на телефоне - может поможет

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в следующем, в имени файла присутствовал знак ":" и из-за него все не работало.